# Garden weed or something else

Tags: weeds

Is the attached bindweed or something else? I have it all over and was planning to treat with glyphosphate as there are a lot of other weeds as well ( poison ivy, creeping charlie)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Z6e.jpg)

[image: Lily of the valley]

Comment: There is no attachment.

Comment: If you click one the 1 the image appears. I will try and edit as well. Thanks.

Comment: Glyphosate doesn't kill everything. In my experience, it has no effect on either lily of the valley or creeping charlie. Dicamba can kill creeping charlie, but I know of no control for lily of the valley except hand-weeding, which is a multi-year task for large patches.

Comment: @Jurp Can lily of the valley ever be a weed? ^.^

Comment: @Stephie,  I live near a university-affiliated arboretum that also has a botanical garden and several old-growth-ish woods. There is a roughly 10 x 15 foot patch of lily of the valley that has out-competed native vegetation. In this site, it is an invasive weed; in fact, in my US state, selling or giving away lily of the valley is illegal because of its invasiveness. A better alternative for home gardens would be Wild Lily of the Valley (Maianthemum sp.), but it goes dormant in late summer, unfortunately.

Comment: @Stephie: it is toxic, and it grows near Allium ursinum (and very confusable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like Lily of the Valley, *Convallaria majalis*. Bindweed has large flowers, grows as a vine, and smaller leaves than Lily of the Valley.

Comment: Lily of the valley , grows in shade and has good perfume.

Comment: Thank you all :).